# Почему при вызове скрипта из udev-правила игнорируется команда sleep?

Tags: linux, sleep, udev

День добрый

Вызываю башевский скрипт при монтировании флешки через udev-правило. Скрипт лежит в `/usr/bin`, в нем прописано:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/sleep 10
<вызов проверки антивируса>
```

Скрипт работает корректно, если его запустить вручную, но при монтировании флешки запускается только вызов антивируса..

Что можно сделать чтобы `sleep` нормально отработал?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1017407/118098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пишут на askubuntu - это можно решить следующим образом:

1. Из правил udev вызываем `/home/user/script1.sh`
2. Из `/home/user/script1.sh` вызываем `/home/user/script2.sh` следующим образом

/home/user/script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo /home/user/script2.sh | at now
```

Пакет `at` возможно придется установить отдельно.

3. /home/user/script2.sh в Вашем случае

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /bin/sleep 10

   <вызов проверки антивируса>
   ```

ссылка на первоисточник https://askubuntu.com/questions/290795/why-is-this-udev-rule-blocking

Связано это с тем, что после завершения события udev убивает процесс, который он вызвал в связи с этим событием